# Calabash error. Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the pass was incorrect. (RuntimeError)

Tags: android, ruby, windows, calabash

I've got this problem when I type

> calabash-android run binary\app-debug.apk features\my_first.feature

on command line in Windows over my project.

This is the problem:

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.9.pre2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:32:in 'initialize': Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password was incorrect. (RuntimeError)

I don't know what it's happening because I set before the password android and the keystore androiddebugkey.

Anyone knows it? Thanks!

PS: I'm using Windows OS 8.

Update 04/30.

Here is debug information:

> JDK fount at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
>   Android sdk found at: C:\Users\MyUser\android-sdk
>   No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
>
> Signature files:
>   C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Temp/d20150430-8916-1taiq7r/META-INF/CERT.RSA
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79/bin/keytool.exe" -v -printcert -J"-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" -file "C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Local/Temp/d20150430-8916-1taiq7r/META-INF/CERT.RSA"
>   MD5 fingerprint for signing cert : FB:3E:80:4F:A2:91:51:59:02:E5:8E:BB:7F:C9:30:EC
>   C:/Users/MyUser/BDD-Calabash-Example-master/binary/app-debug.apk was signed with a certificate with fingerprint FB:3E:80:4F:A2:91:51:59:02:E5:8E:BB:7F:C9:30:EC
>   Keystore location specified in .calabash_settings.
>   Reading keystore data from keystore file 'C:/Users/MyData/.android'
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79/bin/keytool.exe" -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:/Users/MyUser/.android -storepass android "-J"-Dfile.econding=utf-8""
>   Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the pass was incorrect.
>   C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.9.pre2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:32:in 'initialize': Could not list certificates in keystore. Probably because the password was incorrect. (RuntimeError)

EDIT 1 (Apr, 30)

Ok,

so I solved a problem and I got a new one.

I added to my .calabash_settings the debug.keystore to my path and passed. But the new problem is

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.9.pre2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:180:in 'extract_signature_algorithm_name': No signature algorithm names found. (RuntimeError)

Maybe here the problem is that I changed some values in the owner as CN, OU, L, etc, and issuing. How can I change that? I've seen that CN should be Android, not me...

Thanks!

EDIT 2 (May, 1)

I change the debug.keystore with

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -validity 14000

but I've still got the same problem.

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.5.9.pre2/lib/calabash-android/java_keystore.rb:180:in 'extract_signature_algorithm_name': No signature algorithm names found. (RuntimeError)

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: apr-23-2015
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 413942db
Valid from: Thu Apr 23 12:12:36 CEST 2015 until: Thu Aug 23 12:12:36 CEST 2045
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  63:F8:A9:3F:F0:79:1E:A9:6B:9C:B9:AC:EC:6D:66:9B
     SHA1: 3A:BA:29:68:56:29:3E:26:30:E6:B4:2F:24:7A:B1:21:D4:D8:5D:40
     SHA256: 35:89:63:3F:7B:AB:C4:88:DE:B5:40:BE:DF:D1:F7:9F:ED:4B:73:5C:D1:02:B1:69:7D:29:91:84:48:28:2D:46
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
```

Any idea?

EDIT 3 (May, 7).

Solved updating gems with administrator privileges (typed on command line):

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: add -v to run with debug information.

Comment: Edited and added debug information.

Comment: Do you have a file .calabash_settings or calabash_settings in your directory?

Comment: Yes, .calabash_settings file is on the root of my project (BDD-Calabash-Example-master).

Comment: I recommend updating your ruby version to the latest.

Comment: Hi Ottenira, How have you fixed the first issue?